# Help calculating integral

Tags: self-study, integral, pareto-distribution

I need help calculating a integral. It is a Pareto distribution with common tail $\frac{1}{(1+x)^a}$, where I assume countermononicity between two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

$\int_0^1 ( (\frac{1}{1-x})^{-a}-1) ( (\frac{1}{1-(1-x)})^{-a}-1) dx $

when I type this in matlab it answers that I have to define a, but I do not know why I need that?
Can anyone help calculating this and the procedure?
Regards, Søren

Answer (score 6):

If there is no typo in your question it amounts to computing
$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^a\text{d}x-2\int_0^1 x^a\text{d}x+1$$which should not be a problem.

Comment: If I use partial integration, I keep up getting some nasty integrals and I do not come closer to any solution.
Is partial integration the correct technic or is there some other way.

Comment: HInt: No need for partial integration: the first integral is connected with the normalising constant of a [Beta distribution density.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: @Xi'an - this is true but at the same time the beta integral is tough to do from scratch - similar to working out the characteristic function of the Cauchy distribution.  Just one of the integrals stats people "know"!